# How to convert string time to unsigned int in c++

Tags: c++

I need to convert `string` time to `unsigned int` i test my program with `atoi/strtoul/atol` and `string stream` but they don't work correctly what am i missing???

```
 string CurrentTime(){
        time_t rawtime;
        struct tm * timeinfo;
        char bffr [80];

        time (&rawtime);
        timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

        strftime (bffr,80,"%T",timeinfo);
        // puts (bffr);

        return bffr;
    }

    int main(){
    string new_time;
    new_time = CurrentTime();
    stringstream strValue;
        strValue << new_time;
    unsigned int stime;
        strValue >> stime;
    cout<<stime<<endl;
    cout<<new_time<<endl;
    }
```

and

```
 int main(){
        string new_time;
        new_time = CurrentTime();
unsigned int stime =atoi(new_time.c_str());
cout<<stime<<endl;
cout<<new_time<<endl;
```

but both of them print `stime` :just only hour for example `10`

and print `new_time`: for example `10:20:15`

Answer (score 0):

Your string stream is not working because of a delimiter ":". you need to get around it. Try the following code:

```
string new_time;
new_time = CurrentTime();
std::string finalstring;
std::string delim = ":";
size_t pos = 0;
while ((pos = new_time.find(delim)) != std::string::npos)
{
    finalstring += new_time.substr(0, pos);
    new_time.erase(0, pos + delim.length());
}

stringstream strValue;
strValue << finalstring;
strValue << new_time;
unsigned int stime;
strValue >> stime;
cout << stime << endl;
```

Comment: tank you my response is `135559`   hour min sec without `:`

Comment: @girl71 : Nops I dn't think so. In your function strftime you are using "%T" which is a ISO 8601 standard. This the result result should be in HH:MM:SS. Recheck your input and refer http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/

Comment: I recheck response of convert hour min sec without `:` response  `new_time` is true

Comment: `new_time` already work true,,stime doesn't work true print hour  min sec without `:` however tank you

Answer (score -1):

It seems that %T doesn't work well with `strftime` function call.

But there is a workaround for this. `%T` is actually `%H:%M:%S`

Thus,

> strftime (bffr, 80, "%H:%M:%S", timeinfo);

should work fine for your code.

Comment: K.Prabhu  I've tested, but did not change and new_time work correctly my problem in convert string to unsigned int